# Stochastic Continuity of a Lévy Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, levy-processes

Given the following definition of a Lévy Process:

A Lévy Process on $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a $D([0,\infty);\mathbb{R}^d)$-valued random variable $X$ for which $\mathbb{P}\left(X(0)=0\right)=1$ and
$$\mathbb{P}\left(X(t_k)-X(t_{k-1})\in B_k:1\leq k\leq n\right)=\prod_{k=1}^{n}\mathbb{P}\left(X(t_k-t_{k-1})\in B_k\right)$$
for any finite sequence $0=t_0<t_1<t_2<\ldots<t_n<\infty$ whenever $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $B_1,\ldots,B_n\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^N)$.

How do I deduce, directly, that the path of any Lévy process is stochastically continuous, i.e,  $\lim_{s\to t}\mathbb{P}(|X(s)-X(t)|>\epsilon)=0$ ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm thinking that a combination of Fatou's lemma and the Portemanteau theorem might work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By the homogeneity of the increments, we have

$$\mathbb{P}(|X(s)-X(t)|>\varepsilon) = \mathbb{P}(|X(t-s)|>\varepsilon).$$

This means that

$$\lim_{s \to t} \mathbb{P}(|X(s)-X(t)|>\varepsilon) = 0$$

is equivalent to showing that $X(t-s)$ converges in probability to $0$ as $s \to t$. On the other hand, we know that $X$ has cadlag sample paths; this implies in particular continuity at $t=0$, i.e.

$$\lim_{r \downarrow 0} X_r =X_0 =0.$$

As pointwise convergence implies convergence in probability, this finishes the proof.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It makes sense now.